# Pro help: How to sneak out for an interview when I am still newly employed?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, resignation, contractors, employment-agreement

So i had this interview on friday and I have work on that day. I plan to take a half day leave but the problem is I DONT KNOW WHAT REASON TO TELL MY MANAGER WHY I WILL HAVE TO TAKE A LEAVE! Of course I dont want to tell him that I have a job intervieW or he wont approve my leave. I read our policy and says if we ever have engagements or other interests on other companies withib office hours we are going to get suspended so I have to take a leave.

I have just started a week ago and this week would be my second week. I didnt like the job and I was dumb to accept it since it is my first job and didnt actually prepared for this. I hadnt have time to even think about it as the HR was rushing me. So I applied for another job that is in lined with my degree.

I need your professional advises as I have said I am very new on the corporate world and dont want to leave an ugly mark on my reputation.

**FYI**: Would like to make it clear that **I don't want to resign just yet**. I want to make sure that I am secured for the job that I want. I still of course would like to work first. **I am just asking what possible reason do I tell him to approve my leave**.

Comment: No pretty sure mine is a different case. I just got employed for pete's sake

Comment: The answers don't change. You're attending to a personal matter, what exactly you're doing is none of their business. They're your employer, not your mother.

Comment: I know but my manager and the company is very strict on giving leaves. They have to know my reason and they are not contented with "personal matter" excuse. They would not approve my leave with that. plus I just started the job. I won't be worrying as much if Ive been working for months. Ive have just started to work last week and havent done the real job yet..

Comment: Just tell them you have an appointment... you're new, that's a double edge sword.  On one hand, you're afraid of what they'll think, the common practice/courtesy, but on the contrary, in their perspective, they're also afraid of pushing you too hard... so you technically have more leeway than other employees.

Comment: ... __or figure out how to be happy where you are for a little while.__ One week into your first job is not enough time. Everyone goes through an adjustment period when becoming a full-fledged grown-up. Give yourself a chance. But, if you decide to leave soon, sooner would be better.

Comment: @JackD.Ripper Then edit your post to say *why* it is not a duplicate (and preferably do some copyediting). As is, this should be closed.

Comment: @Kent I like the company but my manager told me that I am not qualified to the position I want which is the main reason why I accepted it despite of very low salary and very far from my home. I needed experience for my degree and the position where I am in right now is the only position that they can give me. I dont see any reason to be there, plus I am not much fond of my workmates. They are older and I am very isolated as they are busy too. I am really unhappy with the job and I regret accepting it a lot.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of the question @Lilienthal linked, which seems to involve actually talking with the boss about the situation instead of sneaking out.  Instead, it seems like a possible duplicate of this: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/32372/325

Comment: @MonicaCellio You're right, that's a better match. I linked the other question based on [its top voted answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/24576/25739) which, though basic, is what I would answer: "Just tell them that you have an appointment you need to keep."

Answer (score 3):

> I am just asking what possible reason do I tell him to approve my
>   leave.

Typically, folks call in sick. Usually, that involves the day off. Few employers will question an illness at all. (Apparently, some downvoters don't like this answer. I'm not saying that this is what you *should* do, just that *this is what many folks actually* do in my part of the world - the US).

An alternative is to take time for a doctor's appointment to handle an unspecified condition. That would involve only a partial day off.

Be careful. If your employer requires a note from a physician for a single day of illness or appointment, then this isn't the right approach.

You should also consider trying harder to arrange your interviews either early mornings, or late afternoons. With some employers, coming in late or leaving a bit early isn't an issue at all. Even if it is, many interviews can be held before or after normal working hours if you request that accommodation. When I'm hiring, I often do that for good candidates.

> I have just started a week ago and this week would be my second week.
>   I didnt like the job and I was dumb to accept it since it is my first
>   job and didnt actually prepared for this. I hadnt have time to even
>   think about it as the HR was rushing me.

This time around, learn from your mistake.

Do whatever you have to do to stay on your current company's payroll, so you aren't rushed this time.

And do your homework during the interview process to make sure this job is a much better fit for your needs and desires.

Comment: doctor's appointment. I like the sound of that. But I am expecting lots of interviews and surely couldnt keep that doctors appointment or sick excuse always.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend being dishonest about the reason. Just say you have an appointment. Using sick time when you're not sick is not right, and is likely to have worse consequences if found out (which seems to happen more often that folks admit).

Comment: Just to point out here that use of sick days for this purpose may vary hugely depending on your country of employment and whether your sick days are paid. Here in the UK, sick days are paid and interviews should be done on your own time (ie annual leave), not on sick days. In my opinion, that's disrespectful, unprofessional and also leaving yourself open to all kinds of issues if it's discovered, not to mention being an abuse of trust and potentially even breach of contract if you certify yourself as being sick when you are not. While not applicable for everyone, it's worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is follow your company's procedures on annual leave. It doesn't matter if you're attending an interview or attending a ballet, you're using part of your entitlement to take time off work.

Your new colleagues may think it odd that you're taking days off so soon, but by the sound of it you don't seem intent on staying there anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Just tell them the minimum amount of required information.

You are new, only in your second week. Ask a coworker, or HR, or look in the employee manual to see how you request leave for a few hours. Some companies require forms be submitted, others are much more informal. Some will allow you to shift your work hours during the week to make up the time.

If there is a form fill it out. For reason say: appointment.

Most companies need very little info. They only want to know the date/time, and is it sick or vacation.

If they are one of companies that want all the details. Tell them you have a repairman coming to your house/apartment.

Comment: Yes we do have leave forms but he will go to me and ask me for what particular reasons. They are that clingy. If I say i have a personal matter to attend to he will ask what kind of personal matter otherwise he won't approve. But will try to talk to my agency HR about it.

Comment: HR works fro the company they don't represent you.

Comment: Really? I thought on agencies we have to report on the HR of the agency not directly on the company itself since we are not part of the company? please clarify this.

Comment: If you tell HR "I need time off for an interview" expect management will hear about it seconds after you leave HR.

Comment: No of course I wouldnt dare telling them that I am attending a job interview. I would just tell them that I have personal matters to attend to on that day so i have to take a leave. Better than telling my manager personally, it's more awkward. What do you think?

Comment: If they are as picky as you say, and you are intending to leave anyway, and plan on having lots of interviews in the near future, you should consider just resigning. Normally this is bad advice, but a week ago you were unemployed, so going back to being unemployed after a week won't be much of a change for you. Then you'll be free to find the job you want without worrying about how to take leave.